# ArrayList of classes : ArrayList<Class> but how to force those classes to extend some super class?

Tags: java

I want to manage an ArrayList of classes.

For instance, I have 3 types of filters : `TextFilter`, `DurationFilter` and `TimeFilter` which extend `Filter`.

That seems to be correct :

```
List<Class> filters = new ArrayList<Class>();

filters.add(TextFilter.class);
filters.add(DurationFilter.class);
filters.add(TimeFilter.class);
```

But now I want to restrain the ArrayList type with

```
List<Filter.class> filters = new ArrayList<Filter.class>();

filters.add(TextFilter.class);
filters.add(DurationFilter.class);
filters.add(TimeFilter.class);
```

But it seems that it is not correct. Can you explain why? Do you have a solution to only accept Filter child classes to be adde in my ArrayList? Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to accept only values that come from evaluating `X.class` when `X` is a class extending `Filter`. I believe it's inexpressible in Java's type system.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a ? in generics.

```
List<Class<? extends Filter>> filters = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Filter>>();
```

Since you want class objects and not the instances.

Comment: Have you tried adding an item to such a list. I think adding an item is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to say `List<Class<? extends Filter>>`

See [Upper Bounded Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
 List<Class<? extends Filter>>
```

Class supports Type parameter, and with ? extends Filter you specify every subclass of Filter

Answer (score 0):

I'm no great shakes at Generics, but I believe the syntax is along the lines of

```
List<? extends Filter> filters = new ArrayList<? extends Filter>();
```

Comment: This will restrict the list to instances of `Filter` types, but the OP wants to have a list of *classes*, not instances.